# AsgardCMS Installation Error: 'homestead.page__pages' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, homestead

I've installed https://asgardcms.com/en onto a Laravel Homestead WM twice now and got the error shown below both times when I try open it in a browser.

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 636:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.page__pages' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `page__pages`)
```

[Screenshot on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obk0f.png)

I'm using the default MySQL database settings which are.

DB_HOST=localhost

DB_DATABASE=homestead

DB_USERNAME=homestead

DB_PASSWORD=secret

Everthing seemed fine from the terminal as there no installation issues shown.

Any ideas on what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a database setup issue. Did you ran the install command `php artisan asgard:install` ? This will guide you step by step to set the database up.